# Pandas Dataframe - How to check if the string value in column A is available in the list of string items in column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe which has two columns: Column A contains string and column B contains list of strings.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])
df.loc[0] = ['apple',['orange','banana','blueberry']]
df.loc[1] = ['orange',['orange','banana','avocado']]
df.loc[2] = ['blueberry',['apple','banana','blueberry']]
df.loc[3] = ['cherry',['apple','orange','banana']]

print(df)

           A                            B
0      apple  [orange, banana, blueberry]
1     orange    [orange, banana, avocado]
2  blueberry   [apple, banana, blueberry]
3     cherry      [apple, orange, banana]
```

I want to check for each row to see if the value in column A is listed in the list in column B of the same row. So, the expected output should be:

```
0 False
1 True
2 True
3 False
```

I tried `isin` which works to check against a static list:

```
df.A.isin(['orange','banana','blueberry'])
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

However, when I try to use it to check the list items in the dataframe, it does not work:

```
df.A.isin(df.B)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I would like to avoid for loop and lambda if there is a solution available using Pandas.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have lists in B column same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fun with `sets`

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: set([x])) <= df.B.apply(set)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

#### No loops

But I'd still use the @jezrael's comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(), df.index).eq(df.A, 0).any(1)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

#### Numpy broadcasting

Only works if each list in `B` is of the same length.

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import equal

pd.Series(
    equal(df.A.values.astype(str), np.array(df.B.tolist()).T).any(0),
    df.index
)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

#### `pd.get_dummies`

```
df.B.str.join('|').str.get_dummies().mul(pd.get_dummies(df.A)).any(1)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

#### `np.bincount`

I like this one (-:
However, jezrael notes poor performance )-: so beware.

```
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.B.str.len())
pd.Series(
    np.bincount(i, df.A.values[i] == np.concatenate(df.B)).astype(bool),
    df.index
)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can I use some your graph solution for timings?

Comment: Yes, please do (-:

Comment: I compare last solution and seems very slow `In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.B.str.len())
    ...: b = pd.Series(
    ...:     np.bincount(i, df.A.values[i] == np.concatenate(df.B)).astype(bool),
    ...:     df.index
    ...: )
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 635 ms per loop

In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: a = pd.Series([i in j for i, j in zip(df.A, df.B)])
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.1 ms per loop`

Comment: Wow!  That is really slow (-:

Comment: Yes, I was surprised too.

Comment: I'll mess with it later.  Got to go to bed.

Comment: can you explain when we give axis 1 in this line `pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(), df.index).eq(df.A, 1).any(1)
`

Comment: I don't give `axis=1`... I give `axis=0`.  I do that to ensure we align the index of the the series `df.A` with the index of the resulting dataframe `pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(), df.index)`

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared for all variation of solutions. They showed me a lot different useful tricks.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest is pure list comprehension with check by `in`:

```
m = pd.Series([i in j for i, j in zip(df.A, df.B)], index=x.index)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Solution with `apply`:

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Thank you, @pir for use graph timings solution:

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import equal

def jez1(x):
    return pd.Series([i in j for i, j in zip(x.A, x.B)], index=x.index)

def jez2(x):
    return x.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)

def pir1(x):
    return x.A.apply(lambda x: set([x])) <= x.B.apply(set)
def pir2(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(x.B.tolist(), x.index).eq(x.A, 0).any(1)
def pir3(x):
    return x.B.str.join('|').str.get_dummies().mul(pd.get_dummies(x.A)).any(1)

def pir4(x):
    return pd.Series(equal(x.A.values.astype(str), np.array(x.B.tolist()).T).any(0),x.index)

def pir5(x):   
    i = np.arange(len(x)).repeat(x.B.str.len())
    return pd.Series(np.bincount(i, x.A.values[i] == np.concatenate(x.B)).astype(bool),x.index)
```

---

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 100, 500, 1000],
    columns='jez1 jez2 pir1 pir2 pir3 pir4 pir5'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)
```

---

```
print (res.div(res.min(1), 0))
      jez1        jez2      pir1      pir2       pir3      pir4        pir5
10     1.0   13.235732  4.984622  5.687160  38.796462  1.132400    7.283616
100    1.0   79.879019  6.515313  5.159239  82.787444  1.963980   65.205917
500    1.0  162.672370  6.255446  2.761716  51.753635  3.506066   88.300689
1000   1.0  196.374333  8.813674  2.908213  63.753664  4.797193  125.889481

res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Comprehension is my favorite.

Comment: Added a new one (-:

Comment: Yes.  It should work even if they are different lengths

Comment: @piRSquared - Yes, solution scale bad if larger DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks  @jezrael for putting together all solutions with graph timings. It is really useful to have!

Comment: Thanks  @jezrael for your least expensive solution and putting all sulutions with graph timings. The simplest is the most expensive and least expensive one looks the most complex to me.  I tried this `m = pd.Series([(df.A[i] in df.B[i]) for i in df.index])` which I found the simplest but the time it took   `30.093392, 68.998170, 205.036571, 199.872070` for `10.100.500.1000' respectively.

Comment: @Rafiq, I am really surprised, `pd.Series([i in j for i, j in zip(df.A, df.B)], index=x.index)` seems for me simliest. It zip both columns to tuples (`print(list(zip(df.A, df.B)))`) and then check like my apply solution.  I think this is the most prefer solution, especially easiest and also fastest. Why do you think it is most comlicated? Thank you for explanation.